Como mostrar un porcentaje de avance al procesar un csv con php
estaría agradecido de su ayuda.
Tengo un input file donde se puede cargar un archivo CSV para poder subirlo a una base de datos.
Con el siguiente boton proceso esa subida via Ajax, como podria mostrar un % de avance cuando se vallan insertando las filas del csv, resulta que aveces es un archivo csv de 5000 mil filas
<button class="btn btn-dark ml-2" id="procesar_archivo">Procesar Archivo</button>

Al presionar el botón se procesa el siguiente script;
function procesar_archivo() {
var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('action', 'fetch_data');
    let archivo = document.querySelector('input[name="adjuntar_archivo"]');
    for (let i = 0; i < archivo.files.length; i++) {
        datos.append('archivo[' + i + ']', archivo.files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>logica/insertar/insertar_itinerarios_masivos.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        data: datos,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // if (data.progress !== undefined) {
            //  console.log('Progreso: ' + data.progress + '%');
            //  // Actualizar el progreso en la interfaz de usuario
            //  // Por ejemplo, puedes mostrar el progreso en un elemento HTML
            //  console.log('Progreso: ' + data.progress + '%');
            // } else {
            //  console.log(data.html1);
            // }
            console.log(data.html1);
        }
    });
}

Y este es el script php que procesa
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/generar_pdf.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/rutas.php';

class InsertarItinerariosMasivos {
    public function Insertar(){
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $con = new Conexion(); 
        if(!isset($_FILES["archivo"]) || $_FILES["archivo"]["error"] != 0){
            $csvFile = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

            if (($handle = fopen($csvFile[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                $total_lines = count(file($csvFile));
                $current_line = 0;

                // Recorrer el archivo CSV
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                    // Procesar los datos y hacer la inserción en la base de datos
                    $column1 = $data[0]; // Suponiendo que el primer dato es para la primera columna de tu tabla
                    $column2 = $data[1]; // Suponiendo que el segundo dato es para la segunda columna de tu tabla
                    $column3 = $data[2]; // Suponiendo que el segundo dato es para la segunda columna de tu tabla
                    $column4 = $data[3]; // Suponiendo que el segundo dato es para la segunda columna de tu tabla
                    $column5 = $data[4]; // Suponiendo que el segundo dato es para la segunda columna de tu tabla

                    $insertar = $con->insertar("?,?,?,?,?,?","itinerarios",[NULL,$column1,$column2,$column3,$column4,$column5]);

                    // Calcular y enviar el progreso al cliente
                    $current_line++;
                    $progress = round(($current_line / $total_lines) * 100);
                    echo json_encode(['progress' => $progress]);

                    // Retardo opcional para simular un procesamiento largo
                    // usleep(2500);
                }

                // Cerrar el archivo CSV
                fclose($handle);

                return 'ok';
            } else {
                return "Error al abrir el archivo CSV.";
            }
        }else{
            $html = '   <div class="round-container p-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled><i class="icon-download mr-3"></i>Descargar Presupuesto</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="round-container p-3 mt-3">
                            <p class="m-0">Favor asegurese de llenar todos los campos, además campos como RUT, PATENTE, ETC. Deben cumplir con el formato indicado</p>
                        </div>';
            return ['faltan datos',$html];
        }  
    }            
}

$insertar = new InsertarItinerariosMasivos();

if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "fetch_data"){
    $html1 = $insertar->Insertar();    
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>


Échale un vistazo a esta respuesta a ver si te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260925/1093403

Hola Jonathan, la solución más común es hacer 2 ajax. El 1er ajax es para llamar al script que realiza el trabajo pesado, el cual además procesar guarda el progreso en algún lado (eg: BD, archivo, sesión, etc.). El 2do ajax es para llamar a otro script que lee el progreso donde sea que fue guardado, Obviamente el 2do ajax, debe repetirse cada cierto intervalo tiempo.

Eh intentado con dos Ajax separados, pero no logro dar con el resultado esperado, ya que es como si el primer ajax esperara la respuesta del segundo Ajax para lanzar el resultado, por ende muestra siempre 100%

Intente almacenar el % de avance en una session, pero al ser un ciclo que recorre mas de 4000 filas, la variable de session no esta disponible para ser consulta hasta que no llegue al 100% por su constante cambio
